# onPress of TouchableOpacity gets called when loading Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist with a search function. In the next step, I want something to happen when I press within the item. I'm facing the problem that the TouchableOpacity is visible, but nothing happens when it's pressed. I've tried the same with a Button and face the same issue.

Instead of onPress being called when something is pressed, it somehow get's called once the screen loads immediately. If I for example console.log(item.title) I get all the titles in my console log that are currently in the flatlist.

I've tried to figure out what is causing this for many hours, but can't seem to find any reason. Any help is highly appreciated.

I have a Flatlist that is populated with data, set up as follows:

```
         return (
          <View style={styles.list}>
            <FlatList
              data = {this.state.data}
              renderItem={renderListItem}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
              
            />
     
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    
       const renderListItem = (item) => {
        return (
        
          <MyTouchable
            id={item.item.id}
            title={item.item.title}
      
         
          />
        );
      }
```

MyTouchable Component looks like this:

```
          <View>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={console.log("Pressed")}>
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <View>
       <Text style={styles.text}>{props.id} {props.title}</Text> 
    
       
       </View>
  
      
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to pass the console.log inside an arrow function

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}>
 ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew i was missing something tiny and this was it!

Answer (score 0):

You can’t write like this: `<Component makeThing={myFunc()} />`. You should write like that: `<Component makeThing={() => myFunc()} />` if you are not using `useCallback`.

Make sure to read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render) about passing functions to components.
You must provide and arrow function, and call your function inside it.
Or just use `useCallback` hook:

```
const Component = () => {
  const myFunction = useCallback(() => {
    // do something
  }, []);
  return <AnotherComponent coolFunction={myFunction} />
}
```